# Insuficiente Java Heap space

Tags: java, apache-poi

Estoy usando Apache Poi para trabajar excel desde java y cuando he aumentado la cantidad de filas del excel de 5000 a 100000 me lanza este error, como lo puedo solucionar

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeObject(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:1017)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:1755)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl.synchronizeChildren(DeferredElementNSImpl.java:158)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.getFirstChild(ParentNode.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1402)
>     at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1445)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1403)
>     at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1445)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1403)
>     at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1445)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1403)
>     at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1445)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1385)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1370)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:370)
>     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:164)
>     at
>   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:226)  at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:218)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:408)
>     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:169)  at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:300)
>     at GUI.Principal.jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(Principal.java:735)  at
>   GUI.Principal.access$1100(Principal.java:64)  at
>   GUI.Principal$12.actionPerformed(Principal.java:338)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)  at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)

Comment: Si no añades el código no podemos ayudarte. Tampoco dices cuántas filas intentas generar (¿Mil, diez mil,treinta mil?) o cuantas columnas tienes por fila (¿dos, ciencuenta?). Te aconsejo que mires qué es un [mcve] y añadas más información a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Por desgracia Apache POI consume mucha memoria.

Suponiendo que la máquina donde vas a ejecutar la aplicación tenga suficiente memoria, puedes iniciar la máquina virtual de Java con estos parámetros:

```
java -Xms4096M -Xmx8192M [...] // Resto de parámetros que utilices
```

El primer parámetro (`-Xms`) es el tamaño de heap inicial, y el segundo (`-Xmx`) el tamaño máximo de heap. Puedes jugar con esos valores (te he puesto 4GB y 8GB como ejemplo) para ajustarlo a las necesidades de tu aplicación